# How do I create a custom tab slider animation for PrimeNG TabView?

Tags: css, angular, frontend, css-animations, primeng

I'm trying to create a custom bottom border slider for a PrimeNG TabView. Angular Material has this out of the box but PrimeNG doesn't.

The animation should be a simple border-bottom slide in from left to right or right to left depending on which tab was previously selected.

I tried implementing something with transitions, but I cannot get the border to slide:

```
.p-tabview-nav-link {
   transition: border-bottom 200ms ease-out;
}

.p-tabview-nav-link[aria-selected~="true"] {
   transition: border-bottom 500ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1);
}
```

I am not sure on how to do this.